# Android: Accessing input device msm_pcm_in

Tags: android, android-ndk

I found this one link that provides code to access the phone's input device msm_pcm_in. I was wondering if someone got this to work?

http://android-jotting.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-accessing-input-device-from.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works for me (root access required, of course).